# combining mouseClicked and mouseMoved

Tags: java, mouseevent

In my program, I am trying to make the mouse draw whatever it likes. Instead of using the drag method from the mouse motion listener, I want to make it so that all the user has to do is click once and it can start drawing. I have the mouseMoved method working but I don't know how to enable it only when the mouse is clicked(mouseClicked). Any help is appreciated, I just don't know where to begin.

Comment: Check `evt.buttons` in your `mousemove` handler (if `evt` is the handler's parameter)

Answer (score 0):

its better to set a flag for the mouse click . if flag enable listen the mouse pointer and draw according mouse move

by using MouseMotionListener  you can listen co-ordinates and draw